# How to set Layout to RecyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to load data from server and show in my application (`RecyclerView`), for this job, when the application starts it shows 10 posts and when scrolling `recyclerView` show another post .

I write below codes but when get other 10 posts, **not show** loading layout! I want when get other 10 posts, first **show loading** layout then show other 10 **posts**!

For connect to internet I use **`Retrofit v2`** and for custom `Endless` methos for `recyclerView` I use this class : [EndLess Class](https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e#file-endlessrecycleronscrolllistener-java)

**My Activity codes:**

```
public class Category_page extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener {

    private static final long RIPPLE_DURATION = 250;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView toolbar_title;
    private ImageView toolbar_menuImage;
    private Button categoryCheckNet_button;
    private RelativeLayout root;
    private CategoryAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView cat_recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RelativeLayout loadLayout, checkNetLayout;
    private String catTitle = "";
    private Integer catID;
    private Bundle bundle;
    private int pageCount = 1;
    private Context context;

    private List<R_CatModel> models;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category_page);

        // Hide StatusBar color
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        // Initializing
        context = Category_page.this;
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.category_toolbar);
        cat_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.category_recycler);
        toolbar_title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_pages_title);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.category_root);
        loadLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.category_empty_layout);
        checkNetLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.category_checkInternet_layout);
        categoryCheckNet_button = (Button) checkNetLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkNet_button);
        // Toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        }

        // Receive Data
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        catID = bundle.getInt("categoryID");
        if (bundle != null) {
            catTitle = bundle.getString("categoryTitle");
        }
        if (catTitle != null) {
            toolbar_title.setText(catTitle);
        }

        // Load Data
        loadData();

        // Load Progress
        loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Menu
        View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
        root.addView(guillotineMenu);
        toolbar_menuImage = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_pages_logo);
        new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout_image), toolbar_menuImage)
                .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
                .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
                .setClosedOnStart(true)
                .build();
        // RecyclerView
        cat_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        cat_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        cat_recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {

                Retrofit_ApiInterface apiInterface = Retrofit_ApiClient.getClient().create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);
                Call<R_CatModelResponse> call = apiInterface.getCatMoreResponse(catID, current_page);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<R_CatModelResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Response<R_CatModelResponse> response) {

                        if (response != null) {
                            mAdapter.addNewItem(response.body().getCat_posts());
                            //loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            //loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(Category_page.this, "Error 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            TastyToast.makeText(context, "خطایی رخ داده است", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadData() {
        boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();

        retrofitData(isConnected);
    }

    private void retrofitData(boolean isConnect) {

        if (isConnect) {
            Retrofit_ApiInterface apiInterface = Retrofit_ApiClient.getClient().create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);
            Call<R_CatModelResponse> call = apiInterface.getCatResponse(catID);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<R_CatModelResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Response<R_CatModelResponse> response) {

                    if (response != null) {
                        models = response.body().getCat_posts();

                        mAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(context, cat_recyclerView, models);
                        cat_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                        loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } else {
                        //loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(Category_page.this, "Error 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        TastyToast.makeText(context, "خطایی رخ داده است", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
                    }

                    checkNetLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    //loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //TastyToast.makeText(context, "لطفا برنامه را مجددا باز کنید", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
                    Toast.makeText(Category_page.this, "Error 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Cat_EmptyLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.e("CatResponseError", "Error : " + t);

                }
            });
        } else {
            //loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            checkNetLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                mAdapter.clear();
                cat_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
            categoryCheckNet_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    loadData();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void post_back(View view) {
        onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // register connection status listener
        MyApplication.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
        retrofitData(isConnected);
    }
}
```

**My Adapter codes:**

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<R_CatModel> mDateSet;
    private Context mContext;

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 10;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, List<R_CatModel> dataSet) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDateSet = dataSet;

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();
            recyclerView
                    .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                                    .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                            if (!loading
                                    && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                                // End has been reached
                                // Do something
                                if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                    onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                                }
                                loading = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mDateSet.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.post_card_layout, parent, false);

            vh = new DataViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.progressbar_item, parent, false);

            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_title.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getTitle()));

            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(mDateSet.get(position).getThumbnail_images().getMedium().getUrl())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.post_image)
                    .crossFade()
                    .override(600, 350)
                    .into(((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_image);

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_content.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getContent()));

            // Convert Date ////////
            String date = mDateSet.get(position).getDate();
            String[] parts = date.split(" ");
            String datePart = parts[0];
            String timePart = parts[1];

            int year;
            int month;
            int day;

            String[] dateParts = datePart.split("-");
            year = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[0]);
            month = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[1]);
            day = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[2]);

            JalaliCalendar.YearMonthDate georgianDate = new JalaliCalendar.YearMonthDate(year, month, day);
            JalaliCalendar.YearMonthDate JalaliDate = JalaliCalendar.gregorianToJalali(georgianDate);
            String jalaliDateTime = JalaliDate.toString();

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_dateTime.setText(jalaliDateTime);
            ////////////////////////

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_author.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getCatAuthor().getAuthorName()));
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_author.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    R_CatModel model = mDateSet.get(position);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Profile_page.class));
                    //.putExtra("author", model.getAuthor())
                    //.putExtra("authorID", model.getAuthorID())
                    //.putExtra("authorStatus", model.getAuthorStatus()));
                }
            });

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_category.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.valueOf(mDateSet.get(position).getCategories().get(0).getCatTitle())));
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_category.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = holder.getPosition();
                    R_CatModel model = mDateSet.get(pos);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), PostShow_page.class)
                            .putExtra("title", model.getTitle())
                            .putExtra("image", model.getThumbnail())
                            .putExtra("content", model.getContent())
                            .putExtra("dateTime", model.getDate())
                            //.putExtra("author", model.getAuthor())
                            .putExtra("category", model.getTitle()));

                }
            });

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDateSet.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        mDateSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mDateSet.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addNewItem(List<R_CatModel> newContent) {
        int start = this.mDateSet.size();//contents is a List of your items initialize it your constructor
        int end = newContent.size();
        mDateSet.addAll(newContent);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(start + 1, end);
    }


    public void add(List<R_CatModel> models) {
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void update(List<R_CatModel> models) {
        mDateSet.clear();
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView main_post_title, main_post_content, main_dateTime, main_author, main_category;
        private ImageView main_post_image;

        public DataViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            main_post_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_title);
            main_post_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_picture_image);
            main_post_content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_text);
            main_dateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date_text);
            main_author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_name_text);
            main_category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_category_text);
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public AVLoadingIndicatorView progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (AVLoadingIndicatorView) v.findViewById(R.id.avloadingIndicatorView);
        }
    }
}
```

**My Json :**

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 9,
    "pages": 3,
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "%d8%b3%d8%b1%da%af%d8%b1%d9%85%db%8c",
        "title": "\u0633\u0631\u06af\u0631\u0645\u06cc",
        "description": "\u062a\u0648\u06cc \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u06a9\u0644\u0648\u0646\u06cc \u0647\u0645\u0647 \u0686\u06cc\u0632 \u0648\u0627\u0633\u0647 \u0633\u0631\u06af\u0631\u0645 \u0628\u0648\u062f\u0646 \u0647\u0633\u062a. \u067e\u0633 \u0628\u062f\u0648 \u0628\u0631\u0648 \u062a\u0648\u0634",
        "parent": 0,
        "post_count": 29
    },
    "posts": [{
        "id": 85,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "%d8%b9%d9%86%d9%88%d8%a7%d9%86-%d8%b3%d9%88%d9%85-%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%db%8c-%d8%b1%d9%81%d8%b1%d8%b4",
        "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/?p=85",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "\u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u0633\u0648\u0645 \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0631\u0641\u0631\u0634",
        "title_plain": "\u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u0633\u0648\u0645 \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0631\u0641\u0631\u0634",
        "content": "<p>\u062f\u06cc\u06af\u0647 \u0639\u0635\u0628\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0634\u062f\u0645\u060c \u0686\u0631\u0627 \u0631\u0641\u0631\u0634 \u0646\u0645\u06cc\u06a9\u0646\u0647! :@<\/p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>\u062f\u06cc\u06af\u0647 \u0639\u0635\u0628\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0634\u062f\u0645\u060c \u0686\u0631\u0627 \u0631\u0641\u0631\u0634 \u0646\u0645\u06cc\u06a9\u0646\u0647! :@<\/p>\n",
        "date": "2016-04-20 15:02:26",
        "modified": "2016-04-20 15:02:26",
        "categories": [{
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "%d8%b3%d8%b1%da%af%d8%b1%d9%85%db%8c",
            "title": "\u0633\u0631\u06af\u0631\u0645\u06cc",
            "description": "\u062a\u0648\u06cc \u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u06a9\u0644\u0648\u0646\u06cc \u0647\u0645\u0647 \u0686\u06cc\u0632 \u0648\u0627\u0633\u0647 \u0633\u0631\u06af\u0631\u0645 \u0628\u0648\u062f\u0646 \u0647\u0633\u062a. \u067e\u0633 \u0628\u062f\u0648 \u0628\u0631\u0648 \u062a\u0648\u0634",
            "parent": 0,
            "post_count": 29
        }],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "tellfa",
            "name": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "nickname": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f",
            "url": "http:\/\/codesaz.com",
            "description": "\u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0632\u0646\u062f\u06af\u06cc \u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u062a",
            "avatar": "76"
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [{
            "id": 86,
            "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024.jpg",
            "slug": "wallpapersmania_vol119-024",
            "title": "[WallpapersMania]_vol119-024",
            "description": "",
            "caption": "",
            "parent": 85,
            "mime_type": "image\/jpeg",
            "images": {
                "full": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024.jpg",
                    "width": 1680,
                    "height": 1050
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-150x150.jpg",
                    "width": 150,
                    "height": 150
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-300x188.jpg",
                    "width": 300,
                    "height": 188
                },
                "medium_large": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-768x480.jpg",
                    "width": 768,
                    "height": 480
                }
            }
        }],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "thumbnail": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-150x150.jpg",
        "custom_fields": {},
        "thumbnail_size": "thumbnail",
        "thumbnail_images": {
            "full": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024.jpg",
                "width": 1680,
                "height": 1050
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-150x150.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "medium": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-300x188.jpg",
                "width": 300,
                "height": 188
            },
            "medium_large": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-768x480.jpg",
                "width": 768,
                "height": 480
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I show loading layout when get other 10 posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a layout for loadmore with the progressbar in activity layout and set its visibility to gone , now setVisibility of your loadMore layout to visible programmatically inside public void onLoadMore(int current_page) method and set it back to gone in the response of your webservice(in onResponse and onFailure methods)

**load_more.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/load_more"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/more_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/more_progress"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Loading results..."
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text_size" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity xml file include load_more like -
**listing_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/listing_background"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycleView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text_size"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/noListFound"
                    android:textColor="@color/orange"
                    android:text="No List found Please click here to add a new one"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:padding="@dimen/header_margin"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/load_more"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

**BaseLoadMoreActivity.java**

```
public abstract class BaseLoadMoreActivity extends Activity {
    @BindView(R.id.recycleView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.load_more)
    RelativeLayout loadMore;
    private LinearLayoutManager ll;
    private int page = 1;
    private boolean isNoData = false;
    private boolean isLoading = false;
    private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
            {
                int visibleItemCount = ll.getChildCount();
                int totalItemCount = ll.getItemCount();
                int pastVisiblesItems = ll.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!isLoading && !isNoData) {
                    if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                        loadMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        page++;
                        LoadMoreList();
                        isLoading = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ll = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(ll);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);

    }

    public abstract void LoadMoreList();
}
```

Now extends your **category_page.java** with **BaseLoadMoreActivity** and change code

```
@Override
    public void LoadMoreList() {
        boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();

        retrofitData(isConnected);
    }

private void retrofitData(boolean isConnect) {

        if (isConnect) {
            Retrofit_ApiInterface apiInterface = Retrofit_ApiClient.getClient().create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);
            Call<R_CatModelResponse> call = apiInterface.getCatResponse(catID);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<R_CatModelResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Response<R_CatModelResponse> response) {

                    if (response != null) {
                        models = response.body().getCat_posts();

                        mAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(context, cat_recyclerView, models);
                        cat_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                        loadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        isLoading = false;

                    } else {
                        loadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        isLoading = false;

                        Toast.makeText(Category_page.this, "Error 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        TastyToast.makeText(context, "خطایی رخ داده است", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
                    }

                    checkNetLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    loadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        isLoading = false;

                    //TastyToast.makeText(context, "لطفا برنامه را مجددا باز کنید", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
                    Toast.makeText(Category_page.this, "Error 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Cat_EmptyLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.e("CatResponseError", "Error : " + t);

                }
            });
        } else {
            loadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        isLoading = false;

            checkNetLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                mAdapter.clear();
                cat_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
            categoryCheckNet_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    loadData();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Please remove code of finding recycleView and setting layout manager of it from
**category_page.java** as we did it in  **BaseLoadMoreActivity** otherwise code will not work.

I have just provided code for sample. Hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't implement the `getItemViewType` and `getItemCount` correctly:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position < mDataSet.size()) {
        return VIEW_ITEM;
    }

    return VIEW_PROG;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDateSet.size() + 1;
}
```

additionally replace the `notifyItemRangeInserted(start + 1, end);` with `notifyDataSetChanged();` in `addNewItem`

**EDIT**
keep a boolean `private boolean hasMore = true` in your adapter and edit the `getItemCount()` like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (hasMore)
        return mDateSet.size() + 1;
    else 
        return mDataSet.size();
}
```

You'll have two cases:
 1. If you know from your previous response that there aren't anymore items you can load, set your `hasMore = false` .
 2. If you don't know that, then in your Activity when you get the response in `onLoadMore` if `response== null || response.body() == null || response.body().getCat_posts().size() == 0` set `hasMore = false`.
It all depends on the response you get from the server
**Edit**
in your adapter add a method

```
public void setHasMore(boolean hasMore) {
    this.hasMore = hasMore;
}
```

in the onLoadMore

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<R_CatModelResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Response<R_CatModelResponse> response) {

                        if (response != null) {
                             adapter.setHasMore(response.body().getPages() !=current_page+1)
                             mAdapter.addNewItem(response.body().getCat_posts());
                            //loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            //loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(Category_page.this, "Error 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            TastyToast.makeText(context, "خطایی رخ داده است", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: hey @Drilon Thanks for your help, in your code show me loading layout but when get last post not hide loading layout and show again! however when get last post should hide layout. how to fix it? please help me again

Comment: Do you get in the response something indicating if you can load more items?

Comment: No! can you send me this code again? i am amateur, please help me my friend

Comment: i edit my codes but show me loading layout again! can you send me `onLoadMore` codes for see that i write codes is true or na ?

Comment: Can you help me @Drilan? please

Comment: show me the response.body() that you get in onResponse of the two last pages that you get so i can help

Comment: I write `response.body()` in `onLoadMore` method from above codes !

Comment: no i mean copy the value of the response.body()  ( the json) and paste it here so i can see it

Comment: Please see my update post. this json has one of categories json

Comment: yea because you wrote response.body().getCat_posts(), i wrote wrote response.body().getPages() which is the "pages" attribute in your json

Comment: i edit this, but show me for ever :( why show loading layout for ever ?! :( i am bad lucky

Comment: Can you help me my friend?

Comment: When get last post `loading layout` should hide, it's ok? but in my application when get last post not hide `loadingLayout` and show this again (show `loadingLayout` for ever)

Comment: are you here my friend ?

Comment: why not help me again? :(